# Maven 2- Could not calculate build plan

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2

I set up Maven 2 on my laptop. The reason why I am still using Maven 2 is that Maven, somehow, doesn't work because of the proxy in my company.

The working environment:
Eclipse Helio Service Release 2
Maven 2.2.1
Windows 7

The error message:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'StrutsExample'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I thought it couldn't find the 2.5 jar so I downloaded it and added it into the local repository with the corresponding pom file manually, but it still can't work...

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you configured the proxy in the `settings.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I've configured the proxy in the settings file... @khmarbaise

Comment: Tried to delete the local repo and retry the build?

Comment: Getting Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

Answer (score 8):

My working solution:

- Close Eclipse
- Go to `c:\Users\*yourUser*\.m2\repository` directory
- remove all the files called `m2e-lastUpdated.properties` present on all subdirectories
- Restart eclipse, refresh and Update Maven Projects

My exact error was:

Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4

Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:2.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.

Comment: This is really messed up. Had to do the same but really not sure about the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to resolve build plan:

1. Close eclipse
2. Delete all folders from .m2 repo
3. Start the eclipse
4. keep net connected and let maven update all dependencies

Comment: Tried the same,But doesn't seem to solve my problem.Can you please suggest any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have in trouble with this problem too, and my output is 
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2

And I try several solutions

- List item
- clean the local repository and rerun maven install
- check out if the installation path of maven plugin is true windows>>preferences>>maven>>installations

But these didn't work

Finally I add something like these:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.jpg</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </webResources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

And this solution worked, so add plugins in pom.xml by yourself

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after stoping eclipse, just going to the path that it was complaining about, in your case will be: 
 "C:/Users/yourUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin" and deleting all the files then starting eclipse has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'maven-war-plugin' worked for me. Actually in my `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins` folder there are two versions of maven-war-plugin available. So, I updated it with the latest version(in my case from 2.1.1 to 2.2).